# Hibernate monitor shows only queries without stats

Tags: hibernate, jconsole, hibernate-statistics

I am not able to get detailed statistics for hibernate console monitor(see picture).

Setup:

- Jboss 9
- Hibernate 4.3.10.Final
- Hibernate-jconsole-1.0.7.jar

[image]

Logger:

```
    10:04:40,918 INFO   [org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatisticalLoggingSessionEvent
Listener] (default task-7) Session Metrics {
    318756 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
    29054 nanoseconds spent releasing 1 JDBC connections;
    483861 nanoseconds spent preparing 2 JDBC statements;
    16363812 nanoseconds spent executing 2 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
    398096 nanoseconds spent executing 1 flushes (flushing a total of 9 entities
 and 0 collections);
    7823 nanoseconds spent executing 1 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 en
tities and 0 collections)
}
```

As you can see I am not getting any "Time in DB", "Performance" etc.

Comment: How did you initialize it?